# How to delete AWS Cloudwatch log streams recursively?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have been using AWS Lambda which generates logs into a AWS Cloudwatch log group,
For debugging purpose in a non-prod environment, I find it easier to delete all the log streams,
And run tests on the function to generate fresh logs streams.

I do not wish to delete the log group, because it requires me to set the expiry again.

I found there is a CLI command to delete a log stream
But I wanted to know if I could just delete them all recursively?
Without deleting the log group.

```
delete-log-stream
--log-group-name <value>
--log-stream-name <value>
```

**Reference -**
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/logs/delete-log-stream.html

Comment: I think you mean iteratively.  The log streams aren't a recursive structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to list all the streams and loop through them deleting them one at at time.  This will do it, just set the environment variable GROUP.

```
GROUP=YOUR_LOG_GROUP
for STREAM in $(aws logs describe-log-streams --log-group-name $GROUP  --query logStreams[*].logStreamName  --output text)
do  
    echo aws logs delete-log-stream --log-group-name $GROUP  --log-stream-name $STREAM
done
```